# How to do a Git "sparse" merge

Tags: git

In a mono repo there are two folders, **frontend** and **backend**, and in this repo there are two feature branches, **feature1** and **feature2**.

Considering there are conflicts between those two feature branches, in both folders, **frontend** and **backend**, is it possible to somehow merge only the **backend** folder files, from **feature2** to **feature1** branch?

Note: Im using Git v2.3 and I have tried, among other things, to limit the merge to the **backend** folder using `git sparse-checkout` but the posterior pull/merge command always bring the entire **feature2** branch repo changes, including, of course, the conflicts in the **frontend** folder.

Comment: if you need to do that regularly, you might want to use two repositories (backend and frontend).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't merge *files* in Git, you can only merge *commits*.  (This is not strictly true due to the existence of `git merge-file` but it's where you should start here.)

Note that you don't really merge *branches* either: you merge *commits* and put the new *merge commit* onto a branch.  This need not be the same branch as the two commits you merged.  (Usually it is, and *then* we say that you merged one branch into the other.  But that's not really what's happening: you've really merged *commits*, and then just adjusted one of the two branch names.  Since that's not what Git requires—it only requires merging the *commits* here—we can use a *third* branch name if we like.)

So, you don't want to merge commits X and Y (that have merge base B) because both X and Y have `frontend/*` files:

```
          o--...--X   <-- feature1
         /
...--o--B
         \
          o--...--Y   <-- feature2
```

If you pick either `feature1` or `feature2` and run `git merge other`, you get lots of conflicts in all the `frontend/*` files.  You'd like to completely put those aside and get a merge result of all the `backend/*` files only.

So: Consider making a commit `X2` after `X` and `Y2` after `Y`, perhaps both on new branch names, where `X2` and `Y2` have *only* `backend/*` files (because you removed all the `frontend/*` files).  That is:

```
            o--...--X   <-- feature1
           /         \
          /           X2   <- for-merge-1
         /
...--o--B
         \
          \           Y2   <-- for-merge-2
           \         /
            o--...--Y   <-- feature2
```

You now check out / one of the two `for-merge-...` branch names and run `git merge` with the other one.  Git locates merge base `B` as usual, sees that *both* branches removed *all* `frontend/*` files, keeps the removal of all the `frontend/*` files, and merges each of the `backend/*` files as usual.

You resolve any conflicts as usual, if necessary, and make your new commit on whichever branch you chose for `git checkout`.  (You're using Git version 2.3, which is positively ancient now, and it lacks `git switch`.)  The *commit graph* looks like this now, if I assume you used the name `for-merge-1` as your current branch during the merge:

```
            o--...--X   <-- feature1
           /         \
          /           X2
         /              \
...--o--B                M   <- for-merge-1 (HEAD)
         \              /
          \           Y2   <-- for-merge-2
           \         /
            o--...--Y   <-- feature2
```

Commit `M` has the merged `backend/*` files that you want.  You can now copy those files into a new commit you make after either commit `X`, on `feature1`, or after commit `Y` on `feature2`.  Or you can even do that with both.

(Exercise: what happens if you don't bother making commit `Y2` at all?)